# how to make use of local storage? (when the click function adds data-id to the class then the css color is changed)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried it with the `jquery` code below but it can't be saved in `localstorage`, is there a solution other than the method below?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<a class="abc" data-id="1">Attachments</a>
<a class="abc" data-id="2">Removal</a>
<a class="abc" data-id="3">Hair Loss</a>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".abc").click(function() {
    var dataID = $(this).data('id');
    var idAdd = $(this).addClass("id" + dataID);
    $(idAdd).css({
      "background": "#fcffd6",
      "border": "3px solid #acdcd86b"
    });
    localStorage.setItem("someVarName", $(this).text());
  });

  if (localStorage.getItem("someVarName") != null) {
    var dataID = $(this).data('id');
    var clAD = $(this).addClass("id" + dataID);
    $(clAD).filter(function() {
      return this.innerHTML == localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
    }).css({
      "background": "#fcffd6",
      "border": "3px solid #acdcd86b"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you wanting to save the text in the localStorage and then get it back when page load and apply backgound color to that text ?

Answer (score 0):

The code

```js
var dataID = $(this).data('id');
    var clAD = $(this).addClass("id" + dataID);
    debugger
    $(clAD).filter(function() {
      return this.innerHTML == localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
    }).css({
      "background": "#fcffd6",
      "border": "3px solid #acdcd86b"
    });
```

does not make any sense. What you want to do here is to enumerate and filter all a-elements:

```js
$("a").filter(function() {
      return this.innerHTML == localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
    }).css({
      "background": "#fcffd6",
      "border": "3px solid #acdcd86b"
    });
```